# Notify Facebook users from iOS app: Get notifications to show up in Notifications instead of App Center

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

My iOS app gives the user the option to login using their Facebook account. I would like to be able to see the list with all the friends and invite the ones selected to use the app. The problem is that using the app request window, the friends get a notification that is displayed somewhere in the App Center, rather than in the Notifications panel. Unfortunately, this sort of notification is very subtle and might not be seen until after a long time.

From obvious reasons, I cannot fetch the emails of friends as this would be a great alternative.

Do you know if there is a way to send a Facebook Message or some other sort of notification that is more 'visible' to the receiver? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your problem.  If it's the problem that I think you're having, it sounds like you need to fill out more information on your Facebook App's configuration page.

From what I remember when I had this same issue, you need to have a Canvas URL set in your Facebook App's configuration page.  Even if your app is not going to use Canvas, you need to have that part filled out in order for your friends to receive the app's notification jewel on Facebook.